# Tracing Node warnings during build but --trace-warnings shows no warnings

Tags: node.js, npm-scripts

My project builds fine but I get these warnings during the compiler's operation:

```
Building Angular Package
(node:81809) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:81809) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:81809) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'filename' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:81809) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:81809) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:81809) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'filename' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

In trying to trace down the script that is causing the warning, I have added a --trace-warnings in my package.json scripts on the `serve` script:

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"serve": "node --trace-warnings --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --port 4400",
```

However, this has no effect on the output of the compiler, I still get the same warnings along with the same note to use `node --trace-warnings`